# Did iOS10 remove the ability to read a SQLite database from the bundle?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, ios10

I use 2 SQLite databases: **one is part of the bundle** and stores static/read-only data (called Seed.sqlite), the **other is created on first launch** (or auto-migrated) and is used to save the user data (User.sqlite).

The persistent store managing the read-only database (Seed.sqlite) is setup with the following options:

```
options[NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption] = true
options[NSSQLitePragmasOption] = ["journal_mode": "DELETE"]
```

It works fine under iOS 9.x and under iOS 10 within the simulator, but it crashes when used **on a device running iOS 10** (beta 4 and 8, at least).

I don't have any issue whatsoever with the User.sqlite database.

Up until now, the above configuration was making CoreData complying with the restrictions on a device (ie: bundle files can't be edited).
On iOS 10, it still seems like this is the case: when the above options are removed, temporary files are created (when ran in the simulator, since in that case the bundle is writable), and otherwise, the file is left untouched.
So it seems to behave as it did before, but it still crashes on the device.

Here's where the exception happens. There's a mention of "PFUbiquityTransactionHistoryCache writePendingEntries:". Trying to write something in the bundle might explain the crash, but I don't see why it would be called.

**Calling po $arg1 from the exception returns "Can't create support directory (can't create directory)
(null)"**

```
CoreData`developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform:
    0x189f45ad0 <+0>:   stp    x28, x27, [sp, #-96]!
    0x189f45ad4 <+4>:   stp    x26, x25, [sp, #16]
    0x189f45ad8 <+8>:   stp    x24, x23, [sp, #32]
    0x189f45adc <+12>:  stp    x22, x21, [sp, #48]
    0x189f45ae0 <+16>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #64]
    0x189f45ae4 <+20>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #80]
    0x189f45ae8 <+24>:  add    x29, sp, #80              ; =80 
    0x189f45aec <+28>:  mov    x20, x0
    0x189f45af0 <+32>:  ldp    x21, x19, [x20]
    0x189f45af4 <+36>:  ldr    x23, [x20, #16]
    0x189f45af8 <+40>:  tbz    w23, #2, 0x189f45b08      ; <+56>
    0x189f45afc <+44>:  bl     0x186629c74               ; objc_autoreleasePoolPush
    0x189f45b00 <+48>:  mov    x22, x0
    0x189f45b04 <+52>:  b      0x189f45b0c               ; <+60>
    0x189f45b08 <+56>:  movz   x22, #0
    0x189f45b0c <+60>:  tbz    w23, #13, 0x189f45b14     ; <+68>
    0x189f45b10 <+64>:  dmb    ish
    0x189f45b14 <+68>:  mrs    x8, TPIDRRO_EL0
    0x189f45b18 <+72>:  and    x26, x8, #0xfffffffffffffff8
    0x189f45b1c <+76>:  ldr    x25, [x26, #712]
    0x189f45b20 <+80>:  ldr    x24, [x20, #24]
    0x189f45b24 <+84>:  cmp    x25, x19
    0x189f45b28 <+88>:  b.eq   0x189f45b3c               ; <+108>
    0x189f45b2c <+92>:  cbz    x24, 0x189f45b44          ; <+116>
    0x189f45b30 <+96>:  ldr    x27, [x24, #8]
    0x189f45b34 <+100>: str    x19, [x24, #8]
    0x189f45b38 <+104>: b      0x189f45b48               ; <+120>
    0x189f45b3c <+108>: movz   x27, #0
    0x189f45b40 <+112>: b      0x189f45b4c               ; <+124>
    0x189f45b44 <+116>: movz   x27, #0
    0x189f45b48 <+120>: str    x19, [x26, #712]
    0x189f45b4c <+124>: adrp   x8, 140081
    0x189f45b50 <+128>: add    x8, x8, #2616             ; =2616 
    0x189f45b54 <+132>: ldrb   w8, [x8]
    0x189f45b58 <+136>: cbnz   w8, 0x189f45cb8           ; <+488>
    0x189f45b5c <+140>: ldr    x8, [x21, #16]
    0x189f45b60 <+144>: mov    x0, x21
    0x189f45b64 <+148>: blr    x8
    0x189f45b68 <+152>: and    x8, x23, #0x4
    0x189f45b6c <+156>: tbnz   w23, #12, 0x189f45b9c     ; <+204>
    0x189f45b70 <+160>: tbnz   w23, #1, 0x189f45bf4      ; <+292>
    0x189f45b74 <+164>: cbz    x8, 0x189f45c24           ; <+340>
    0x189f45b78 <+168>: cbz    x22, 0x189f45b84          ; <+180>
    0x189f45b7c <+172>: mov    x0, x22
    0x189f45b80 <+176>: bl     0x18a0a76ac               ; symbol stub for: -[PFUbiquitySwitchboardCacheWrapper init]
    0x189f45b84 <+180>: adrp   x8, 134549
    0x189f45b88 <+184>: ldr    x1, [x8, #1568]
    0x189f45b8c <+188>: movz   w2, #0
    0x189f45b90 <+192>: mov    x0, x19
    0x189f45b94 <+196>: bl     0x186622f20               ; objc_msgSend
    0x189f45b98 <+200>: b      0x189f45c24               ; <+340>
    0x189f45b9c <+204>: cmp    x8, #0                    ; =0 
    0x189f45ba0 <+208>: cset   w8, eq
    0x189f45ba4 <+212>: cbz    x22, 0x189f45bb4          ; <+228>
    0x189f45ba8 <+216>: tbnz   w8, #0, 0x189f45bb4       ; <+228>
    0x189f45bac <+220>: mov    x0, x22
    0x189f45bb0 <+224>: bl     0x18a0a76ac               ; symbol stub for: -[PFUbiquitySwitchboardCacheWrapper init]
    0x189f45bb4 <+228>: and    x22, x23, #0x1000
    0x189f45bb8 <+232>: tbz    w23, #0, 0x189f45bcc      ; <+252>
    0x189f45bbc <+236>: mov    x0, x21
    0x189f45bc0 <+240>: bl     0x186ab6998               ; _Block_release
    0x189f45bc4 <+244>: mov    x0, x20
    0x189f45bc8 <+248>: bl     0x18a0a71fc               ; symbol stub for: -[PFUbiquityTransactionHistoryCache writePendingEntries:]
    0x189f45bcc <+252>: movz   w21, #0
    0x189f45bd0 <+256>: cbz    x22, 0x189f45c3c          ; <+364>
    0x189f45bd4 <+260>: cmp    x25, x19
    0x189f45bd8 <+264>: b.eq   0x189f45ca0               ; <+464>
    0x189f45bdc <+268>: str    x25, [x26, #712]
    0x189f45be0 <+272>: cbz    x24, 0x189f45c78          ; <+424>
    0x189f45be4 <+276>: cmp    x27, x19
    0x189f45be8 <+280>: csel   x8, xzr, x27, eq
    0x189f45bec <+284>: str    x8, [x24, #8]
    0x189f45bf0 <+288>: b      0x189f45c78               ; <+424>
    0x189f45bf4 <+292>: adrp   x8, 134548
    0x189f45bf8 <+296>: ldr    x1, [x8, #3312]
    0x189f45bfc <+300>: mov    x0, x19
    0x189f45c00 <+304>: bl     0x186622f20               ; objc_msgSend
    0x189f45c04 <+308>: cbz    x22, 0x189f45c10          ; <+320>
    0x189f45c08 <+312>: mov    x0, x22
    0x189f45c0c <+316>: bl     0x18a0a76ac               ; symbol stub for: -[PFUbiquitySwitchboardCacheWrapper init]
    0x189f45c10 <+320>: adrp   x8, 134549
    0x189f45c14 <+324>: ldr    x1, [x8, #1568]
    0x189f45c18 <+328>: movz   w2, #0
    0x189f45c1c <+332>: mov    x0, x19
    0x189f45c20 <+336>: bl     0x186622f20               ; objc_msgSend
    0x189f45c24 <+340>: tbnz   w23, #0, 0x189f45c30      ; <+352>
    0x189f45c28 <+344>: movz   w21, #0
    0x189f45c2c <+348>: b      0x189f45c3c               ; <+364>
    0x189f45c30 <+352>: mov    x0, x21
    0x189f45c34 <+356>: bl     0x186ab6998               ; _Block_release
    0x189f45c38 <+360>: movz   w21, #0
    0x189f45c3c <+364>: cmp    x25, x19
    0x189f45c40 <+368>: b.eq   0x189f45c50               ; <+384>
    0x189f45c44 <+372>: str    x25, [x26, #712]
    0x189f45c48 <+376>: cbz    x24, 0x189f45c50          ; <+384>
    0x189f45c4c <+380>: str    x27, [x24, #8]
    0x189f45c50 <+384>: tbnz   w23, #0, 0x189f45c68      ; <+408>
    0x189f45c54 <+388>: adrp   x8, 134548
    0x189f45c58 <+392>: ldr    x1, [x8, #32]
    0x189f45c5c <+396>: mov    x0, x19
    0x189f45c60 <+400>: bl     0x186622f20               ; objc_msgSend
    0x189f45c64 <+404>: b      0x189f45c78               ; <+424>
    0x189f45c68 <+408>: mov    x0, x19
    0x189f45c6c <+412>: bl     0x187aae3e8               ; CFRelease
    0x189f45c70 <+416>: mov    x0, x20
    0x189f45c74 <+420>: bl     0x18a0a71fc               ; symbol stub for: -[PFUbiquityTransactionHistoryCache writePendingEntries:]
    0x189f45c78 <+424>: tbz    w23, #13, 0x189f45c80     ; <+432>
    0x189f45c7c <+428>: dmb    ish
    0x189f45c80 <+432>: cbnz   w21, 0x189f45cdc          ; <+524>
    0x189f45c84 <+436>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #80]
    0x189f45c88 <+440>: ldp    x20, x19, [sp, #64]
    0x189f45c8c <+444>: ldp    x22, x21, [sp, #48]
    0x189f45c90 <+448>: ldp    x24, x23, [sp, #32]
    0x189f45c94 <+452>: ldp    x26, x25, [sp, #16]
    0x189f45c98 <+456>: ldp    x28, x27, [sp], #96
    0x189f45c9c <+460>: ret    
    0x189f45ca0 <+464>: str    xzr, [x26, #712]
    0x189f45ca4 <+468>: cbz    x24, 0x189f45c78          ; <+424>
    0x189f45ca8 <+472>: cmp    x27, x25
    0x189f45cac <+476>: b.ne   0x189f45c78               ; <+424>
    0x189f45cb0 <+480>: str    xzr, [x24, #8]
    0x189f45cb4 <+484>: b      0x189f45c78               ; <+424>
    0x189f45cb8 <+488>: adrp   x8, 134550
    0x189f45cbc <+492>: ldr    x1, [x8, #2768]
    0x189f45cc0 <+496>: mov    x0, x19
    0x189f45cc4 <+500>: bl     0x189f3ea64               ; _PFAssertSafeMultiThreadedAccess_impl
    0x189f45cc8 <+504>: b      0x189f45b5c               ; <+140>
    0x189f45ccc <+508>: bl     0x186610720               ; objc_begin_catch
    0x189f45cd0 <+512>: and    x22, x23, #0x1000
    0x189f45cd4 <+516>: orr    w21, wzr, #0x1
    0x189f45cd8 <+520>: b      0x189f45bd0               ; <+256>
    0x189f45cdc <+524>: bl     0x1866106f0               ; objc_exception_rethrow
    0x189f45ce0 <+528>: b      0x189f45c84               ; <+436>
    0x189f45ce4 <+532>: mov    x19, x0
    0x189f45ce8 <+536>: b      0x189f45cf4               ; <+548>
    0x189f45cec <+540>: mov    x19, x0
    0x189f45cf0 <+544>: tbz    w21, #0, 0x189f45cf8      ; <+552>
    0x189f45cf4 <+548>: bl     0x186610768               ; objc_end_catch
    0x189f45cf8 <+552>: mov    x0, x19
    0x189f45cfc <+556>: bl     0x186ca4ed4               ; _Unwind_Resume
    0x189f45d00 <+560>: bl     0x186610794               ; objc_terminate
```

And here's the device crash log:

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x187bd81c0 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x18661055c objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreData                        0x189f9ff14 -[NSSQLCore externalDataReferencesDirectory] + 992
3   CoreData                        0x18a05ef44 -[NSSQLFetchRequestContext initWithRequest:context:sqlCore:] + 424
4   CoreData                        0x189f9eba4 -[NSSQLCore processFetchRequest:inContext:] + 76
5   CoreData                        0x189ea1510 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 504
6   CoreData                        0x189f8183c __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 4512
7   CoreData                        0x189f79f88 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _routeHeavyweightBlock:] + 276
8   CoreData                        0x189ea11c4 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 408
9   CoreData                        0x189e9fbec -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 572
10  CoreData                        0x189f50b88 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentObjectsForFetchRequest:inContext:error:] + 456
11  CoreData                        0x189f51390 __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 584
12  CoreData                        0x189f53638 internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 92
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x186a611c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x186a6e860 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 84
15  CoreData                        0x189f409a8 _perform + 232
16  CoreData                        0x189f51080 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 188
17  CoreData                        0x189e9fbec -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 572
18  MagicalRecord                   0x101b5b274 0x101b48000 + 78452
19  CoreData                        0x189f45b68 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 152
20  CoreData                        0x189f45a48 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 260
…
```

**Edit**

- Re-creating the Seed database under iOS 10 doesn't solve the issue
- Copying the file from the bundle into the app container (with NSFileManager) on first launch and then using that one solves the issue. But then it takes twice the space (database in the bundle + copy), it's the solution I managed to avoid up until now (at least it proves everything else works as expected)

Comment: What are the details of the crash? Update your question with relevant details.

Comment: @rmaddy I added the crash log

Comment: No you didn't. That's not a crash log, it's just some code.

Comment: @matt Indeed, my attention got caught by the "writePendingEntries". I added the relevant part of the device log.

Comment: @Nycen It seems that Core Data needs to write some ancillary information, and it can't do that inside your app bundle. I would suggest copying the database out to a writable location and using it there. I understand that you regard it as read-only, but try it and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @matt It doesn't. Running on the simulator always works, so I used that for testing. Giving the coordinator standard permissions results in CoreData creating -wal and -shm files within the bundle and modifying the .sqlite file, which of course is forbidden on the device. But with ReadOnly permissions, the file remains unchanged and no temporary file is created, which is the behavior expected and complies with device restrictions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no, you can still do that… BUT if you have a **Binary Data** attribute with **Allows External Storage**, then it will crash.

Because of that, a .Seed_SUPPORT folder with a _EXTERNAL_DATA subfolder is created, even if the models that allow external storage are not in the Seed configuration.

So to fix it:

- create a **.xxx_SUPPORT** folder (replace xxx with the name of your sqlite file), next to your xxx.sqlite seed file
- create a subfolder named **_EXTERNAL_DATA** inside
- BONUS: create a **.gitkeep** file inside _EXTERNAL_DATA, so that git commits the folder
- add that folder to XCode, make sure to add it with "Create folder references", not "Create Groups"

You'll probably need to see hidden files in the Finder, for that just run:

- defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
- killall Finder

You can set it back to NO afterwards.

Comment: Arnaud ... I have a .xcdatamodeld that does not have a Binary Data attribute with Allows External Storage but I can only make it read from app bundle by using your trick above. Is there something else I should look for in the .xcdatamodeld?

Comment: @GregRobertson Do you have a Binary Data attribute? Maybe they changed some settings since I posted this and behave like that whatever you checked. I haven't had to use that trick since, so unfortunately my understanding is limited to the above.

Comment: I had some for fetches in the model but I deleted them and still got error. It must somehow keep the old attribute. The folder trick works but seems more of a hack since it’s not documented. Thanks for replying.